# Android studio: Android project can't run on a different OS , possible errors

Tags: android

What could be the possible errors and ways to solve them?
I encountered:
..app\build\intermediates\external_file_lib_dex_archives\debug with an error name: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException.

I tried clean and rebuilding, doesn't work.
Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Try deleting the build folder. Make sure you make a copy of the project first.

Comment: Ok, I  have written that as a formal answer, so mark it as a valid answer. I am glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting the build folder. Make sure you make a copy of the project first.  The build folder is used by Grade to build the project source and its dependencies in to a project. Deleting this directory is generally safe, and sometimes as you have experienced, this is necessary as it can get in a problematic state.